# Get custom options from WordPress options table

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom options being stored in the database like this:

```
option_name: shop_details

option_value: {"shop_name":"My shop","shop_slug":"my-shop","shop_description":"This is my cool shop.","shop_start_date":"2019-10-03","shop_end_date":"2019-10-11","shop_owner":"1","taxonomy":"shop"}
```

I am trying to display some of this information on the front-end, like this:

```
$shop_options = get_option('shop_details');
echo $shop_options['shop_description'];
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'shop_description' in D:\www\my-shop\wp-content\themes\shop-city\taxonomy-shop.php on line 32 {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: wouldn't you be looking for the option named `shop_details` based on `option_name: shop_details`?

Comment: @lagbox yes sorry - my bad. I screwed up get_option() while editing. Fixed now, but the problem remains of course.

Comment: What is the value of  $shop_options? can you print it?

Comment: @Darshkhakhkhar print $shop_options returns exactly the same as the option_value mentioned above. So, exactly this: {"shop_name":"My shop","shop_slug":"my-shop","shop_description":"This is my cool shop.","shop_start_date":"2019-10-03","shop_end_date":"2019-10-11","shop_owner":"1","taxonomy":"shop"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you are getting in `$shop_options` is a **JSON** format, so you have to decode it first then you can get the array. Use:

```
$shop_options = get_option('shop_details');
$shop_options = json_decode($shop_option);
```

If you call `json_decode($somestring)` you will get an object and you need to access like `$object->key`, but if you call `json_decode($somestring, true)` you will get a dictionary and can access like `$array['key']`

Comment: or you can directly use $shop_options =json_decode(get_option('shop_details'));
that will also work..

Comment: I think you meant `json_decode($shop_options);`

That returns `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array...`

Comment: Yep, I just found that as well (on another thread). `$shop_options = json_decode($shop_options, true);` solves the problem. Thanks!